# CSV retain CRLF while replacing LF

Tags: java, unix, csv

I have a csv file as follows (control characters in bold)

```
"ID","NAME","CLASS"CRLF
"1","JOHN X","A"CRLF
"2","DOELF
Y","B"CRLF
"3","OTHER S", "D"CRLF
```

Please note that line 3 ends with LF and not CRLF. While reading this CSV file in Java, I get 5 lines instead of 4 (header line + 3 data line). Is there a way I could replace LF with space while retaining CRLF (either massage the input file or change java code). I did lot of googling and I could see that every solution replaces LF along with CRLF.

Thanks

Comment: dos2unix converted all CRLF to LF. However I need to remove all LF and retain CRLF

Comment: @jlordo, your solution involves reading the entire content of a file into a string, however my file size is around 2GB. Sorry I forgot to mention file size in the main post

Comment: @jdev.hari: why don't you just read lines until you find one that ends in CRLF?

Comment: @nneonneo the java api's just returns the line once it seems either CRLF or LF. There is no way to figure out once it is read as to what the line separator was.

Comment: @jdev.hari: then you will have to write your own line reader. It's not that hard: read chunks of, say, 80 chars at a time, look for `\r` and split if you find one. Otherwise, replace `\n` characters and keep accumulating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Scanner` with a delimiter of `\n`. Using jlordo's technique to get rid of the `LF`, you write the content to some `OutputStream` one line at a time. This way you never have the whole 2GB+ file in memory

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {   
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Soto\\Downloads\\person.xml");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
    String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator"); // Assuming you are on Windows, otherwise set it to \n
    scanner.useDelimiter(lineSeparator);
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); // would be a real outputstream, like FileOutputStream
    char LF = 0xA; 

    while (scanner.hasNext()) { // looks up to the next delimiter
        String line = scanner.next();
        line = line.replace("" + LF, "");
        out.write(line.getBytes());
        out.write(lineSeparator.getBytes());
    }

    // the OutputStream now contains the content with new lines but no LF
}
```

`LF` is hexedecimal `A`, see [here](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/c0.html).

Comment: if LF is replaced by system line separator I would end up reading 5 lines in Java. I want to read only 4 lines i.e LF shouldn't be considered as line separator. I am open to modifying the input file through unix commands or modifying the java file read logic.

Comment: @jdev.hari I seem to have misunderstood the goal. You want to get rid of the line with `LF`? Give me a sec.

Comment: @jdev.hari The above should work. You can write to a new `OutputStream` (maybe a temporary file) so that you don't have the whole file in memory.

Comment: @jdev.hari Any progress?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
char LF = 0x0A;
char CR = 0x0D;
String content = ... // your lines(s)
content = content.replaceAll("(?<!" + CR + ")" + LF, " ");
```

The regex is constructed to replace `LF` with a space only if there is no preceeding `CR`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: This is what OP says: "_Is there a way I could replace `LF` with space while retaining `CRLF`_" ... and it's exactly what my answer does.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis sorry if my question is confusing. I donot want to replace the whole line, but just get rid of LF i.e. Java sees line 2 as "2","DOE Y","B"

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: My answer is logically correct, but OP didn't mention his file is 2GB large, so my answer is not practical as it involves reading the whole thing into a string variable.

Answer (score -1):

You have to setup the correct System Property (line.separator) as explained here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Hope it solves the problem. 
Cheers